# What happens in a unimolecular reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

Molecularity is defined as the number of molecules required to collide simultaneously to form a product in an elementary reaction.

In a unimolecular elementary reaction, do two molecules of the same species collide or does a single molecule dissociate?

Comment: ?!? If *two* molecules collide, you have a *bi*molecular reaction.

Comment: Just for future reference, *As homework is considered literal homework, exams, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.*

Comment: @Karl Is reaction $\ce{A + A ->[collision \Delta E ] A^{*} + A -> B + C + A}$ unimolecular ?

Comment: Isn’t that the unimolecular, bimolecular etc. defined by the no. Of distinct species (eg. NaCl AND KOH, and not NaCl and NaCl) ?

Comment: Ionic compounds are not the best example.  $\ce{2 N -> N2}$ is bimolecular. Generally, bimolecular elementary reaction is A + B -> products different to  A, B, with A possible be the same as B.

Comment: Just found the right link https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/03%3A_Rate_Laws/3.02%3A_Reaction_Mechanisms/3.2.01%3A_Elementary_Reactions

Comment: @Poutnik __elementary reaction__

Comment: @Karl  It is conventionally still considered as elementary reaction $\ce{A -> B + C}$. Collisions providing activation energy are not considered as reactions. Instead of the 2nd A, it could be a helium atom.

Comment: @Poutnik If A* is an identifiable intermediate (as your first eq. above explicitly says!), then A-->B+C cannot be an elementary reaction. You're barking up the wrong tree ;)

Comment: @Poutnik The elementary reaction in that case is $\ce{A^* -> B +C}$ !

Comment: @Karl  Lakedaimonians would say  IF....   A* is not identifiable intermediate, it is just A with higher then ground energy. Compounds have dozens of different energy states. Many reactions use A as implicit A*, A -> B + C is always A* -> B + C as A does not have enough energy. // My point since the beginning was that unimolecular reaction can be triggered by molecular collision as one of possible form to reach activation energy. I have thought it was clear.

Comment: @Poutnik My point was you shouldn't call it A* and put it in an equation without square brackets if it's just thermal. And I don't know if thermal decomposition in the gas phase is actually 100% unimolecular. Probably not.

Comment: @Karl I have not talked about any particular reaction. Is $\ce{A ->[thermal collision with A] B + C}$ better ?

Comment: Well, a certain fraction of "A" particles in the thermodynamical ensemble is *always* above the energy limit in your thought experiment. To discuss it, you need to decide if thermal collisions happen at a far higher rate than the inverse lifetime of your [A*] state, or not. In the former case, you are clearly unimolecular, and A* is not worth mentioning. In the former, your gas is not even in thermodynamic equillibrium (*or* the reaction is superfast, if you're in a more dense state, i.e. you won't have time to investigate the kinetics. ;))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127285/discussion-between-poutnik-and-karl).

Comment: Often other inert molecules collide with the reactant molecules, allowing the reaction to take place, but since those inert molecules are not counted in the rate law, the reaction is considered "unimolecular".

Comment: What is called a unimolecular reaction in textbooks is normally (a) an isomerisation such as cis $\ce{<=>}$ trans isomerisation or dissociation $A\to$ products or in the gas phase (b) the reaction $\ce{A + M<=> A^* + M, A^*\to }$products usually described by the Lindemann scheme or more advanced by RRKM theory. Here $A^*$ is a collisionally activated molecule.

Answer (score 5):

Truly collisionless unimolecular reaction are rare, as even highly unstable molecules must be triggered somehow to gain the reaction activation energy.

This is frequently obtained as an energy gain by thermal collision with other molecule, or by a photon absorption. Collisions are usually much more frequent, but photons are usually much more energetic than thermal collisions.